# Need to pass a variable to OnLoad() from a PHP header() redirect

Tags: php, javascript, html, onload

I have a PHP variable thePHPvar in a file DoStuff.php in my website.
thePHPvar gets set to a string.

Then after that the code in DoStuff.php does

```
header("Location: http://localhost/theWebite/index.php");
```

I need 2 things in my onLoad handler inside the body tag of index.php:

```
<body onload="doLoad()">
```

My doLoad() function must be able to do 2 things:

1) get access to 'thePHPvar' variable, which again is a string (a path name) that was set in PHP code in DoStuff.php just prior to the header() redirect.

2) also, doLoad() must be able to detect when 'thePHPvar' is empty so it can avoid trying to use
    'thePHPvar' and skip the logic that uses that string.

I'm new to php and javascript and have impressed myself with getting working what I have now,
but I've spent 1/2 day on this, read lots of similar issues on SO.

I have to be able to redirect back to index.php, grab this string variable and if it's been set (not null), execute some javascript code.

Right now this is all my onLoad() does, and hey -- it works.  But not the right way, yet.

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">

function doLoad()
{
   alert("Page is loaded");
}
</script>
</head>
```

Without introducing a bunch of new stuff I'd have to learn like Ajax etc., how can I get this done in javascript, html, php and what I have here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a [session variable](http://www.tizag.com/phpT/phpsessions.php) as Jorge said, if this myPHPVar is specific to a user. Otherwise, pass the variable in your header redirect:

```
header("Location: http://localhost/theWebite/index.php?myVar=" . $myPHPVar);
```

As you're a beginner, you probably won't want to use JSON to get the variable from PHP to Javascript, but do look it up if you ever have to pass a lot of data to Javascript code.

```
<script>
    var myPHPVar="<?php echo $_GET['myVar']; ?>";
</script>
```

If the user has any influence over that PHP variable, be sure to [sanitise the variable against XSS attacks.](http://chriscook.me/web-development/php-preventing-typical-xss-attacks/)

To check if myPHPVar is empty in your `doLoad` method, just use `if (!myPHPVar) { .... }`

Answer (score 2):

Would it be acceptable to include `$thePHPvar` in the querystring of the page you're redirecting to?

```
header("Location: http://localhost/theWebite/index.php?$thePHPvar");
```

and then in javascript you can just look for `document.location.search`, eg

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function doLoad()
{
   alert('thePHPvar is ' + document.location.search.substring(1));
}
</script>
</head>
```

Comment: I thought of that too, but since it's a pathname it would be good to use something less tamperable like a session.

Comment: +1 @digital, thank you.  I really learned a lot from all the responses, and as usual it really feels odd to have to accept only one.  I'll wait for a bit to do that.  Thanks again to everyone!

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you set a session with the variable you want and then use the session to fetch the variable on the next page.
After initializing the session on the page you redirected to, you'd use it on the javascript like this:

```
var variableFromPhp = "<?php echo $the_variable ;?>";
alert(variableFromPhp);
```

Comment: +1 @Jorge, thanks -- question, and sorry if it sounds naive but that's my level of understanding right now that's coming through -- will $the_variable be visible to a user of the browser if they do a 'View Page Source' in the browser?  It doesn't matter for me here in , but I'm curious to learn this point -- thanks.

Comment: @wantTheBest no, your PHP source is aprsed server side, and it will never be visible, only the output. HTML, CSS and JavaScript are all parsed on the client and are sent to the client.

Comment: If you echo $the_variable (or any other variable) in the html explicitly, yes, it's value will be visible just like any other variable in the Javascript.

Answer (score 1):

You could pass it as a GET param, but that's generally less secure since it's tamperable.

Previous page:

Then on the page you redirect to:

```
 <head>
 <?php 
  session_start();
  $the_var=(isset($_SESSION['a_var']) && $_SESSION['a_var'])) ?
      $_SESSION['a_var']
      : false;
?>
<script type="text/javascript">

function doLoad(the_var)
{
   if(the_var){ alert("Page is loaded"); }
}
window.onload=function(){ doLoad(<?php echo var_export($the_var,true);?>); }
</script>
</head>
```

Comment: +1 @Cole Wow, this is cool stuff, ties it all together, html and php and javascript, thanks, I like it.